# Program doesn't jump in Delegate-Method

Tags: debugging, delegates, ios4

Good Morning Community,

I have a problem, because I have implemented an CoverFlowViewController.m with an Delegate method, but the Debugger NEVER jump in this method, does anyone know why?
Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *weiter = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    weiter.frame = CGRectMake(100, 400, 120, 40);
    [weiter addTarget:self action:@selector(goToChart) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    NSString *ansicht = @"Weiter";
    [weiter setTitle:ansicht forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:weiter];
    // loading images into the queue
    loadImagesOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    NSString *imageName;
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"cover_%d.jpg", i];
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
        UIImage *aktuellesImage = imageView.image;
        UIImage *scaledImage = [aktuellesImage scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(100.0f, 100.0f)];
        [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setImage:scaledImage forIndex:i];
    }
    [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setNumberOfImages:10];

}

- (void)openFlowView:(AFOpenFlowView *)openFlowView selectionDidChange:(int)index{
    NSLog(@"%d is selected",index);
}
```

Does anyone know why the Debugger (= the Programm) never jump into the selectionDidChange() method?

I have no solution since three days, and hope somebody could help me?

Greetings and Thank you beforehand
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you connected the viewDelegate to your viewController?
Please add `NSLog(@"Delegate: %@", ((AFOpenFlowView*)self.view).viewDelegate);` at the end of your viewDidLoad method to see if it is connected.

Comment: Hey fluchtpunkt, I have added your line, and the Console says:    2010-11-08 13:44:52.478 CoverFlow[1504:207] Delegate: (null)
What should I have to do, that it works?

Answer (score 0):

Add

((AFOpenFlowView *)self.view).viewDelegate = self;  on the init or viewDidLoad method